# Restify: API version in URL

Tags: node.js, routes, restify

Currently under development of API with restify and still cannot get used to specifying the API version in headers. It just doesn't seem very user friendly.

Is there any way for version to be part of url?

Example would be:

```
http://domain.com/api/v1/action
```

Or even better in my case:

```
http://api.domain.com/v1/action
```

Thanks

Comment: I think that apart from just declaring those routes yourself (`app.get('/v1/action', ...)`), Restify doesn't support this sort of scheme.

Comment: @robertklep hm that's what I thought so.. too bad

Comment: It seems like it might be easier to do something like /api/action?v=1, though I have yet to figure out a graceful way to handle this.

Comment: I think using it as a part of url is better than as a parameter.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Also you can use Restify to define your versions:

```
var server = restify.createServer({
    name: 'myAPI',
    versions: ['1.0.0', '2.0.0']
});
```

Then using this middleware with `server.pre`:

```
server.pre(function (req, res, next) {
    var pieces = req.url.replace(/^\/+/, '').split('/');
    var version = pieces[0];

    // only if you want to use these routes:
    // /api/v1/resource
    // /api/v1.0/resource
    // /api/v1.0.0/resource
    if (!semver.valid(version)) {
        version = version.replace(/v(\d{1})\.(\d{1})\.(\d{1})/, '$1.$2.$3');
        version = version.replace(/v(\d{1})\.(\d{1})/, '$1.$2.0');
        version = version.replace(/v(\d{1})/, '$1.0.0');
    }

    if (semver.valid(version) && server.versions.indexOf(version) > -1) {
        req.url = req.url.replace(version + '/', '');
        req.headers['accept-version'] = version;
    }

    return next();
});
```

Finally, in your routes you can do something like this:

```
server.get({ path: '/resource/:id', version: '1.0.0' }, function () {
  // send object in version 1.0.0
});

server.get({ path: '/resource/:id', version: '2.0.0' }, function () {
  // send object in version 2.0.0
});
```

Examples:

- http://api.domain.com/resource/10
- http://api.domain.com/2.0.0/resource/10
- http://api.domain.com/1.0.0/resource/10

The above examples follow the standards, because if version is not specified through header or url, shows the last version.

**UPDATE**:

I made a plugin to have API versions in URL:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/restify-url-semver

Comment: Thanks for great answer would that also work with versions as "v1", "v2" etc?

Comment: You can get `pieces[0]` and then transform it to a valid semver, e.g. v1 to 1.0.0, or v1.0 to 1.0.0, or v.1.0.0 to 1.0.0

Comment: Now you can use with v1, v2, v3, etc. and add with dots v1.0, v2.0, v3.0, v1.2.3, etcetera

Answer (score 4):

People are correct that it's not supported by restify, but I thought I'd throw my solution to this problem into the mix. I'm doing something like this (warning, untested code to follow):

After I create a server, but **BEFORE** I declare the routes, I register a custom parser to translate the url-style version specifier into an HTTP-style specifier:

```
server.use(versionParser);
```

And versionParser.js looks something like this:

```
var semver = require('semver');
var restify = require('restify');

module.exports = function (req, res, next) {

    // we expect every request to have the form "/api/[api-version]/..."
    // verify that the api-version is a valid semver value
    var urlPieces = req.url.replace(/^\/+/, '').split('/');
    var api = urlPieces[0];
    var apiVersion = urlPieces[1];

    if (api !== 'api' || !semver.valid(apiVersion)) {
        return next(new restify.InvalidContentError({message: "Invalid Version Specifier"}));
    }

    req.header('Accept-Version', apiVersion);
    return next();
}
```

This way, the restify routes can inspect the Accept-Version header as they do naturally.

*Sidenote*: The semver part is probably not relevant to this answer, but I wanted to verify that the API version in the URL was a valid semver value, as it allows flexibility in the URL values such that a user could take advantage of restify's flexibility in version specifiers.

Comment: Injecting the request, interesting. I think you would have to do a tiny bit more work to take care of cases when people actually specify the version header, and also need a bit of thought that restify supports versions in format x.x.x but otherwise, good and effective answer

Comment: @Tom Good thoughts.  semver.valid does enforce that it's x.x.x, so I _think_ that would cover it.  As for checking to see if they initially put it in the Accept-Version header, that's a good thought that I could see being especially useful in the case of a migration from one format to the other.

Comment: Honestly I haven't use semver yet so not exactly sure what does it do. But anyways in my case, it would be rather easy without it as well. I don't see when I would be using other version than 1, 2, etc. So simple version+'.0.0' would do